# Stored procedure if exists not giving correct answer

Tags: stored-procedures, exists

I created a sql 2005 stored proc to tell me if the CRID I am searching for is approved by the supervisor. [SuperApproved] is a bit, [CRID] is char(36).  Even if the CRID doesn't exist, I am still getting 1.
Any help in writing this?

```
USE [cr_Saturn2]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  Randy Baker
-- Create date: 10/12/2010
-- Description: Check for Approved CRID in CostReportTracking
-- =============================================
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[st_Is_CostReportApproved]
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @myECR char(36) = null  
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

if exists(
 select [CRID]
 from [dbo].[CostReportTracking]
 where [SuperApproved] = 1)

 -- exists- cost report is Approved by Supervisor
 select 1
else
 -- does not exist
 select 0    
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add an `and [CRID] = @myECR` somewhere. Right now you are just checking if there is **any** record that has been *SuperApproved*.

Comment: oops - yes - my bad! you are definetely correct.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @randy you are welcome. If my answer helped you, then please accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark to the left.